# Network load balance router

Tags: load-balancing

i have Airtel broadband and a Tata broadband connection. i have around 50 PCs connecting

through a airtel broadband connection. both are dsl connections with my phone line going

into dsl modems and a Ethernet cable going from dsl modem directly into switch. currently

only airtel connection is connected with static ip on my private lan and usings the airtel

isp DNS servers as dns ip address and the default gate way as 192.168.1.1 (ip add of the

dsl modem). All PCs are connected in a work group.
when in full use my users complain of certain web pages not opening. when i ping internet

addresses like yahoo or Google i get 2 reply packets and 2 lost packets. i suspect that a

single broadband connection is not able to sustain 50 simultaneous downloads/browsing. is

there any device which connect to both DSL and make one line so that its give me high 
speed simultaneous browsing & which Network load balance router i can use ????
Help needed urgently. thank you all to those who reply.

Answer (score 0):

To load balance those connections the easiest way it to have a single router connecting both wan links and using an equality weighted static route for the two connections.
Having a balanced route like this can cause problems with applications if traffic for a service is coming from two different public IPs; that is why it is best to use a policy based route so that established connections route through the same interface.

I am only really familiar with cisco products, I would suggest a router from their branch range.